# Displaying star rating with Font Awesome icons

Tags: php

Looking to display a score based on a value stored in $averageScore. The value varies from 0 to 5. This is what I currently have, but looks bloated and I am looking for a cleaner solution with PHP:

```
if( $averageScore = 0 && $averageScore < 0.5 ) {
  $starPattern = array('e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 0.5 && $averageScore < 1 ) {
  $starPattern = array('h', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 1 && $averageScore < 1.5 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 1.5 && $averageScore < 2 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'h', 'e', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 2 && $averageScore < 2.5 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'e', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 2.5 && $averageScore < 3 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'h', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 3 && $averageScore < 3.5 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'f', 'e', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 3.5 && $averageScore < 4 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 4 && $averageScore < 4.5 ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'e');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 4.5 && $averageScore < 5) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'h');
} elseif( $averageScore >= 5  ) {
  $starPattern = array('f', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'f');
}

foreach( $starPattern as $ratingStar ) {
  if( $ratingStar == 'e' ) {
    echo '<i class="far fa-star" text-yellow></i>';
  }
  if( $ratingStar == 'h' ) {
    echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>';
  }
  if( $ratingStar == 'f' ) {
    echo '<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>';
  }
}
```

I also have something similar, but it does not cover half stars. I have been trying to combine both, but without success.

```
$value = $averageScore;
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  if ($value >= $i) {
    echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL;
  } else {
    echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure there's even more concise ways to do it, but here's one way to do it a bit more concise than your initial attempt:

```php
$averageScore = 2.5;

// get integer value of $averageScore
$wholeStarCount = (int) $averageScore;
// get integer value of 5 - $averageScore
$noStarCount    = (int) (5 - $averageScore);
// is $averageScore - $wholeStarCount larger than 0?
$hasHalfStar    = $averageScore - $wholeStarCount > 0;

$stars = str_repeat('<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>' . PHP_EOL, $wholeStarCount) .
         ($hasHalfStar ? '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>' . PHP_EOL : '') .
         str_repeat('<i class="fas fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL, $noStarCount);
         
echo $stars;
```

An example `$averageScore = 2.5` prints:

```
<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star"></i>
```

---

You could of course make it more concise by omitting the intermediate variables at the start and put the expressions directly into the string concatenation. I just wanted to put them up top for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my go at it.

I wrote these functions:

```
//Check if value is float/decimal  
function is_decimal($val){
    return is_numeric($val) && floor($val) != $val;
}

function printWholeStars($var){
  for ($i = 0; $i < $var; $i++) {
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>';
  }
}

function printHalvStars(){
  echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>';
}

function printEmptyStars($totalStars,$var){
  $emptyStars= floor($totalStars-$var);
  for ($i = 0; $i < $emptyStars; $i++) {
   echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
  }
}

 function printScores($totalStars, $averageScore){
  if (is_decimal($averageScore)) {
    $averageScoreRound=floor($averageScore);
    printWholeStars($averageScoreRound);
    printHalvStars();
    printEmptyStars($totalStars,$averageScore);
  }else{
    printWholeStars($averageScore);
    printEmptyStars($totalStars,$averageScore);
  }
}
```

Then use them:

```
$averageScore = 1.5;
$totalStars   = 5; 
printScores($totalStars,$averageScore);
```

Output:

```
<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks! This returns 4 empty stars and one half star with an average score of 4.55. But thanks for your input!

Comment: @Jonathan Sorry, I put the wrong FontAwesome code in printWholeStars - I fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Bolli answer above:

here's OOP code:

```
class Reviews {

public function star( $size = 'full' ) {
        if ( $size === 'empty' ) {
            echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>';
        } else if ( $size === 'half' ) {
            echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>';
        } else {
            echo '<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>';
        }
}

public function avg_star_rating( $avg ) {
        $totalStars = 5;
        if ( is_numeric( $avg ) && floor( $avg ) != $avg ) {
            $averageScoreRound = floor( $avg );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $averageScoreRound; $i++ ) {
                $this->star( 'full' );
            }

            $this->star( 'half' );

            $emptyStars = floor( $totalStars - $avg );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $emptyStars; $i++ ) {
                $this->star( 'empty' );
            }
        } else {
            $averageScoreRound = floor( $avg );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $averageScoreRound; $i++ ) {
                $this->star( 'full' );
            }

            $emptyStars = floor( $totalStars - $avg );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < $emptyStars; $i++ ) {
                $this->star( 'empty' );
            }
        }
}

}

$reviews = new Reviews();
$reviews->avg_star_rating(1.5);
```

output:

```
<i class="fas fa-star text-yellow"></i>
<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
<i class="far fa-star"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines.

```
$fullCount = floor($averageScore);
$hasHalf = ($averageScore % 1 > .5) ? true : false;

for ($i = 1; $i <= $fullCount; $i++) { // Add full stars
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL;
}
if ($hasHalf) { // Add half star
   echo '<i class="fas fa-star-half-alt text-yellow"></i>'.PHP_EOL;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5 - $fullCount; $i++) { // Add empty stars
    echo '<i class="far fa-star"></i>' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! This returns only 4 full stars with an average score of 4.55. Not exactly what I was expecting. But I appreciate the feedback!